# What does zstyle :compinstall filename do?

Tags: zsh

The Zsh first-run config wizard usually adds

```
zstyle :compinstall filename '$HOME/.zshrc'
```

to the newly generated `~/.zshrc`.

What is the purpose of this directive? I could find some documentation on zstyle in general, but not on the specific config key.

Comment: It appears to be caching related per code in `Completion/compinstall` so that that code can find a non-default location for what is usually `~/.zshrc` (which subsequent code looks for if the style is unset).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's for when you run `compinstall` again. It lets `compinstall` find where it has written out `zstyle` statements for you last time. This way, you can run `compinstall` again to update them.

You can read about it here in the source code: https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Completion/compinstall#L52

Comment: permalink: https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/c7da34dd71966bfa0531cb87414c103c989f205c/Completion/compinstall#L52